# Toggling extensions off/on in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I suspect I have an extension conflict. Is there an easy way to turn off all extensions, then turn them back on, retaining their enabled/disabled state? I know in the command palette there is the option to "Disable All Installed Extensions for this Workspace" and then "Enable All Extensions for this Workspace" but the enable part doesn't reset it to what I had previously, it does what it says: it enables *all* installed extensions. I would like the extensions previously disabled to remain disabled.

If it matters:

- OS: MacOS 12.3
- VS Code: 1.65.2

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to do strictly what you're looking for, but one solution could be to install [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aaronpowell.vscode-profile-switcher) which allows profiles to be made.

Make a new profile to mess around with your extension combinations, whilst preserving your current config in a main profile, and you should be able to do what you want to I believe.